# Find string that appears after or before a string on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I want to find text that occurs after a certain string of text on a webpage. Apologizes if this is a simple question, I am new to JavaScript.

For example, if, on a webpage, the string "Description: File" appears, how would I find what appears after "Description: " using JavaScript? The description is in a table, if it helps, like so:

`<TR><TD>Description:</TD><TD>File</TD></TR>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the Id of the table it's in and that you can be reasonably sure that you want the whole contents of the cell, you can use something like this.

```
var searchFor = "Description";
var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');
var tds = tbl.getElementsByTagName('td');
var desc = '';
for(var i = 0;i<tds.length;i++){
    if(tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchFor) >= 0){
        desc = tds[i+1].innerHTML;
        break;
    }
};
```

The data you want will be in the `desc` variable.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ3ty/)

Comment: The table does not have an Id - I should have mentioned that. Very helpful code regardless however, thank you! Is there any other way I can locate the table? This is for a userscript so I can't edit the page unfortunately. **Edit:** Looks like `document.getElementsByTagName("table")` solves my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: well, if you know the exact page layout you could write code to get it. for example if it's the only table in the document, you can get the table with `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]`


**Edit**: didn't see your edit. Glad you fixed it!